# How to get user data from custom user model in django?

Tags: python, django

This is my User Model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_email
```

This is my User Model View.

```
def userdetails(request):

    username = request.user.get_username()
    password = request.user.get_password()

    users = User.objects.get(user_email=username)
    user_list = {
        'users': users
    }
    if request.user.check_password(password):
        print(password)
        return render(request, 'userdetails.html', user_list)
    else:
        return render('/', {'user': request.user.username}) # I dont know what this line is doing
```

and This is my Template.

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Login</h1>

        <div class="mt-3"></div>


        {{ form.username.label_tag }}
        {{ form.username }}

        <div class="mt-3"></div>

        {{ form.password.label_tag }}
        {{ form.password }}

        <div class="mt-3"></div>

        {{ form.errors }}


        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>

    </form>
```

I am unable to get the user data from the Login Template. Is there any way to work with the current User Model?

Comment: I would really suggest you to go with Django built in authentication system it has much more functionality. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/]

Comment: this two lines of code `username = request.user.get_username()  |  password = request.user.get_password() `  change them to `POST -> username = request.POST.get('username')   password = request.POST.get('password')`